# I need help in filtering the content of this SQL column

Tags: sql, oracle, filtering

I need help in filtering the content of this SQL column. I have unfortunately been unsuccessful so far. I will be happy for any assistance.

My goal is for all the unc paths to bear the same format. 
All should look like: \\ps9\wa033242. Meaning all should begin with the "\\"   replacing the "///"

I tried truncating it but because of the different string length, I have problems.

I tried truncating and UPDATING

```
SELECT
    cw_platz.nummer,
    cw_platz.nwaddress,
    cw_platz.bezeichnung,
    os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.ldruckernr,
    os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.papierschacht,
    os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.treibername,
    cw_logischerdrucker.bezeichnung
FROM
    cw_platz,
    os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz,
    cw_logischerdrucker
WHERE
    cw_platz.nummer = os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.platznr and
    cw_logischerdrucker.nummer = os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.ldruckernr and
    cw_platz.bezeichnung in cw_platz.bezeichnung
```

This is my result:

[image]

Comment: don't post data sample as  image ..  post as  text

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to string handling many products have their own functions.)

Comment: Specify the expected result too. (As formatted text - no images wanted.)

Comment: Hello. I am using SQL developer.

Comment: . All results should look like: \\ps9\wa033242. Meaning all should begin with the "\\" replacing the "///"

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to simply use something like REPLACE(yourstringhere, '/','\').
Is it something you already tried?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes I did. I used       UPDATE os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz,cw_platz,cw_logischerdrucker
SET TRIEBERNAME = REPLACE('TRIEBERNAME', ('///', '\\');

Comment: I did but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

you could use replace

```
select  replace('client/ps9///wa033242//', '/' ,'\');.
```

and for update

```
update  your_table  
set your_column = replace(your_column,  '/' ,'\')
```

try avoid ..  the where like

```
UPDATE os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz
SET os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.treibername = REPLACE(os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.treibername,  '/' ,'\')
 FROM
    cw_platz,
    os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz,
    cw_logischerdrucker
WHERE
    cw_platz.nummer = os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.platznr and
    cw_logischerdrucker.nummer = os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.ldruckernr and
    cw_platz.bezeichnung = cw_platz.bezeichnung
```

Comment: what mean  'It did not work' .. you have error ? show the error message  ..  wrong result  ..  show a clear data sample  (as text  ..and not as an image)  your actual result and your expected  result

Comment: UPDATE os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz 
SET os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.treibername = REPLACE(os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.treibername, '///','\\') 
 FROM
    cw_platz,
    os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz,
    cw_logischerdrucker
WHERE
    cw_platz.nummer = os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.platznr and
    cw_logischerdrucker.nummer = os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.ldruckernr and
    cw_platz.bezeichnung in cw_platz.bezeichnung
and TREIBERNAME like '///%'

Comment: you commeny have not sense  .. to me .. .. if you have error show the error message  ..

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL-Befehl wurde nicht korrekt beendet
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Fehler in Zeile: 19 Spalte: 1

Comment: answer  updated ..  with  suggestion  and a differente slash pattern  `'/' ,'\'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you.

```
UPDATE os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz
SET os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.treibername = REPLACE(os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.treibername, '\\','///') 
 FROM
    cw_platz,
    os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz,
    cw_logischerdrucker
WHERE
    cw_platz.nummer = os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.platznr and
    cw_logischerdrucker.nummer = os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz.ldruckernr and
    cw_platz.bezeichnung = cw_platz.bezeichnung
and TREIBERNAME like '\\%'
```

Comment: I did as you suggested Sir but it failed.

UPDATE os_cw.cw_ldzuplatz,cw_platz, cw_logischerdrucker
SET treibername = REPLACE(treibername, '\\','///')
WHERE TREIBERNAME like '\\%'

Comment: Because there are three tables involved.

Comment: Hello , the original code  I posted above shows that there are three tables.

Comment: The UPDATE  key word is marked red.   Error message : The SQL command was not properly ended.

Comment: I am using SQL developer.

Comment: I still get the same error message after I retried the code. The UPDATE word is marked red.